# Recording Audio and Video with mediaMuxer examples?

Tags: android, recording, encoder, mediamuxer

I am trying to record audio and video with mediaMuxer.  I followed the example for video recording from https://github.com/google/grafika but when I tie in an audiostream it results in a broken video over half the time.  Does anyone know of any examples or tutorials that show how to record both audio and video properly?

Comment: Hey @QuinnBaetz have you done this recording audio and video both.???